# Properties of functions with smooth Schwarzian derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Are there any interesting conditions under which one can be certain that the Schwarzian derivative of a function is smooth at a given point? For example, a general function $f(z)$ with a finite-order pole at $z=a$ behaves like $S(f) \sim (z-a)^{-2}$ near $z = a.$ Under certain conditions on the coefficients of the series representation of $f$, we'll find that the $(z-a)^{-2}$ term and $(z-a)^{-1}$ terms in $S(f)$ vanishes, and $S(f)$ is smooth.

What I'm looking for is a nice intuitive criterion for when the Schwarzian is smooth at a given point, something that doesn't depend on some system of equations for the coefficients of $f$. I'd like to be able to say "if the function $f$ has X interesting property near $a$, we can be sure that $S(f)$ is smooth at $z=a$." Does any such thing exist?

Comment: Please define Schwarzian derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove that local univalence is necessary and sufficient (either $f'(a) \ne 0$ or $f$ has a simple pole at $a$) for $S(f)=\frac{d}{dz}\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)})^2$ to be analytic near $a$.

Sufficiency - here we just need to check the simple pole case as $f'(a) \ne 0$ obviously implies $f'(z) \ne 0$ near $a$ and then clearly $S(f)$ analytic there by definition; but if $f=\frac{c}{z-a}+g(z), c \ne 0, g$ analytic near $a$, we can compute $f'(z)=-\frac{c}{(z-a)^2}+g'(z),f''(z)= \frac{2c}{(z-a)^3}+g''(z)$, hence:

$\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}=\frac{-2}{z-a}(1+(z-a)^2h(z))=\frac{-2}{z-a}-2(z-a)h(z)$, with $h$ analytic near $a$, hence:

$S(f)=\frac{2}{(z-a)^2}-2((z-a)h(z))'-\frac{2}{(z-a)^2}-4h(z)-2((z-a)h(z))^2$ is analytic near $a$

Necessity: if $f'(a)=0$ then if $n \ge 1$ is the order of the zero, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}$ in $S(f)$ is $-n-\frac{1}{2}n^2<0$, so $S(f)$ has indeed an order two pole at $a$. Similarly if $f$ has a pole of order $n \ge 2$, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}$ is $n+1-\frac{1}{2}(n+1)^2 < 0$, so again $S(f)$ has a pole of order two.

As an aside $S(f)$ which is invariant under Mobius transforms of the unit disc when $f$ is analytic inside the unit disc gives one of the few general analytic conditions for a (meromorphic) function in the unit disc to be univalent but not necessarily satisfy other restrictions like starlike, convex, spiral-like etc, namely Nehari's Theorem, claiming that if:

$|S(f)(z)| \le \frac{2}{(1-|z|^2)^2}$, (note that this automatically implies local univalence as otherwise, LHS goes to infinity near a non-local-univalent point inside the disc) then $f$ univalent in the unit disc.

Conversely, it is not hard to prove that for univalent functions we have the same inequality satisfied but with $6$ instead of $2$

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help